# Changing a foreach loop to an if statement for reading a text file C#

Tags: c#

Okay, so this is the code I have but I am trying to figure out how to change this foreach loop to an if statement. I've been trying to figure it out by myself but it doesn't seem to be working the way I want it to. So if anyone could help that would be much appreciated. Just as something extra, I am still a noob at C#. :)

```
// Used to make sure that the script can read the text file
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader ("Maze.txt")) 
    {
        lineArray = File.ReadAllLines("Maze.txt");

        // Access one line at a time
        foreach (string line in lineArray)
        { 
            // Reset X axis for each line of the file
            int x = 0;

            // Access each character in the file
            foreach (char c in line)
            {
            string currentPosition = c.ToString();
            newFilePosition = Convert.ToInt32(currentPosition);

            if (newFilePosition == 1)
            {
                // Create a cube on the X axis
                NewCubePosition = new Vector3 (x, y, 0);
                Instantiate (g_mazeCubes, NewCubePosition, Quaternion.identity);
            }
            // Loop until X axis is done
            x++;
        }
    // Loop until Y axis is done
    y++;
}
}
```

Comment: `foreach` and `if` are totally different things... I'd understand if you wanted to convert a `foreach` to a `while` for instance, but I don't get what you're after. Please explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, a while loop would be awesome as well. I've just used foreach way too much and need to change it, so I thought an if statement would be able to help me do that.

Comment: Why do you think you've used a `foreach` loop way too much?

Comment: you mean converting a `foreach` to a `for` that test a condition?

Comment: I'm new to using this website so I'll try and clarify what I'm trying to do. I am trying to use a text file to create a maze in unity but I have used foreach loops too much in the rest of my code so I would like to use a different way of accessing all of the 1s and 0s in the text file to make the maze.

Comment: If you need to loop through every character of every line in a text file there's nothing wrong with using a couple of `foreach` loops. But see my answer if you want to reduce your code a bit. And the fact that you're using a text file to store the data is going to limit your options.

Comment: Why are you even declaring and initializing the `StreamReader` ? It's not used anywhere in your code.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are refering to transform a `foreach` to a `for` that test an condition. Making this transformation in code means you **don't** need to set `x=0` and `y=0` before and *increment* them inside `foreach` loop.

Using `for` you will do  [initialization, the condition, and the afterthought](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Traditional_for_loops) of `x` and `y` and iterate through array at once.

As many say you don't neet `StreamReader`. `File.ReadAllLines` [opens and close the file for you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsy4fhsa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
lineArray = File.ReadAllLines("Maze.txt");

// Access one line at a time
for (y = 0; y < lineArray.Count(); y++)
{
    string line = lineArray[y];

    // Access each character in the file
    for (int x = 0 ; x < line.Count(); x++)
    {
        char c = line[x];
        string currentPosition = c.ToString();
        newFilePosition = Convert.ToInt32(currentPosition);

        if (newFilePosition == 1)
        {
            // Create a cube on the X axis
            NewCubePosition = new Vector3 (x, y, 0);
            Instantiate (g_mazeCubes, NewCubePosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the code with a bit of LINQ, but I don't think there's anything you can do to get rid of the inner loop.

```
var lineArray = File.ReadAllLines("Maze.txt");

for (var y = 0; y < lineArray.Length; y++)
{
    foreach (var c in lineArray[y].Select((value, i) => new { Character = value, Index = i })
                                  .Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Character) == 1))
    {
        Instantiate(g_mazeCubes, new Vector3(c.Index, y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

(You also don't need the `StreamReader`)

In my opinion if you try to reduce the the code further than this you'll obfuscate the intent with no benefit.